# Identifier ID already been declared in reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am getting the above error with my `reducer`, how can I use the `id` in both switch cases?

```
case "SUBMIT_ANSWER":
    const { current, results, completed, id } = action.data;

    return state.map(video =>
        video.id === id
            ? { ...video, current, results, completed }
            : video
    );
case "RESET_QUIZ":
    const { id } = action;
    console.log("action", action);
    console.log("state", state);
    return state.map(video => {
        video.id == id
            ? {
                  ...video,
                  completed: false,
                  current: 0,
                  results: {
                      correctAnswers: 0,
                      score: 0
                  },
                  totalScore: 0
              }
            : video;
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple.... just wrap the code of each case in curly braces {}

For e.g.

```
case '1': { your code here }
case '2': { your code here }
```

let has block scope. Since there is only one block which starts with switch. Thus all the variables persist in the whole switch block.

After inserting braces {} in each case, they will work as a scope of your variables. After scope is over the variable cannot be used after that.